# Memory leak related to OptionsMonitor<LoggerFilterOptions> and Serilog

Tags: asp.net-core, memory-leaks, serilog

I have what looks to be a memory leak in a production web service related to OptionsMonitor and Serilog. Over a period of about 10 days the memory usage gradually increases from starting point of ~200MB up to ~1GB at what point it hits Kubernetes limits and Out of Memory Exceptions start being thrown. K8s then restarts the pod as it is seen as unhealthy.

- asp.net core 3.1 alpine docker image
- Serilog 2.9.0
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 3.1.3
- Running on Amazon AWS EKS Kubernetes 1.20

I got some dumps from the production container and was able to analyse with JetBrains dotMemory tool. It is pointing to OptionsMonitor having the Largest retained size. There are ~300k instances of Serilog.Core.Logger being retained in memory also that are attached to the OptionsMonitor onChange event that gets fired. I think this happens when configuration updates. Although there is nothing explicitly updating the configuration files so I am not sure why this keeps firing. I am not sure why these objects are not being released from memory. Here is a couple of screenshots from dotMemory with the overview and then a retention graph which shows Serilog.Core.Logger attached to OptionsMonitor. Any ideas what is going on here?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hX0y.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKX0h.png)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that comes across this I eventually figured it out myself. The serilog integration being used was not the standard one that overrides the defualt LoggerFactory with the SerilogLoggerFactory. The standard LoggerFactory was still being used which has some code to register to any changes made in the config files and any log filtering changes. That seems to cause an issue when only the LoggerProvider is replaced with the SerilogLoggerProvider. Something not getting cleaned up. The SerilogLoggerFactory does not register for any changes to LogFilerOptions so once I changed to the standard Serilog integration the memory issue went away.